# Python alternative to google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an app that I am working on that is currently hosted on google App engine. It is written in python and went pretty smoothly until my requirements changed and google app engine would not let me do what I needed to do. Currently I am trying to find a way to host my code (python) and be able to make and accept http:// requests, and be able to edit/add files in the same directory as the python scripts are located (I need to store lots of files, and the blobstore is just weird).

If this is not possible, I would be happy with being able to run python scripts "in browser" like when testing with google app engine, just on my local machine (windows 7 64 bit).

Any help is appreciated

Comment: AFAIK, App Engine's web-facing part is largely based on [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com), which you can (maybe easily) host yourself.

Comment: If there's some requirement that makes your app unsuitable for App Engine, it would probably help if you told us what that is, since it'll probably affect what alternatives are suitable. If it's just "blobstore is weird", it's the way it is for good reasons - and writing to the local filesystem isn't a good practice in large scale systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's App Engine supports WSGI , not CGI.

You should be able to port your code to another stack that supports WSGI rather painlessly.  There isn't much custom google-specific stuff on there.

Some popular frameworks that support WSGI include:

- Pyramid
- Tornado
- CherryPy
- bottle
- flash
- web.py
- twisted

There are lots more

In terms of hosting:

- Heroku can host Python WSGI apps
- You can deploy on virtually any machine with uwsgi , apache's mod_wsgi, or countless other wsgi servers
- Most frameworks have their own server for local development

Comment: the difficulty will be in porting to another ormish datastore. especially if the OP is using things like list properties and structured properties.